# Ввод русских символов

Tags: c++, кодировка, visual-c++

Создаю структуру

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

const int num = 5;

struct Student  {
    string name;
    int groupNumber;
    int progress[num];
};
```

и использую её в программе

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

int n;
cout << "Введите количество студентов в группе n = ";
cin >> n;
cin.ignore();

Student * Group = new Student[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cout << "Введите ФИО: ";
    getline (cin, Group[i].name);
    Group[i].groupNumber = rand()%5 + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        Group[i].progress[j] = rand()%5 + 2;
    }
}

int check = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        sum += Group[i].progress[j];
    }
    double count = (double)sum/5;
    if (count < 4) continue;
    cout << "\n\n" << Group[i].name;
    cout << "\nГруппа: " << Group[i].groupNumber << "\nСредний бал: " << count;
    ++check;
}
if (check == 0)
{
    cout << "\nВ массиве нет студентов, средний бал которых выше 4";
}

cout << "\n\n";

delete [] Group;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Латинские символы вводятся нормально, а вместо русских потом выводятся кракозябры.  Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Перестать учиться программировать в винде.

Реальная проблема в том, что консоль по умолчанию работает в кодировке **cp866**, а все остальное (файлы, параметры командной сторки, environment) в **cp1251** (она же ANSI).

--

Здесь Вы не первый с таким вопросом. Проще почитать ответы, задав в гугле

    site:hashcode.ru кракозябры

что-то похожее.

Comment: попробуйте перейти на `wstring` и перевести консоль в Unicode-режим.